# Що таке "папля"?

Tags: значення-слів

Доброго дня!
Зустрів це слово у такому контексті: "Ні дуба, ні клена... Лише землі
вклоняються лячно вбогі **паплі**: тремтять  на  вітрах,  і  в  тиші  тремтять, готові  лягти  під  подув  розп'ять..." [Жученко Григорій "Туга"](http://www.poetryclub.com.ua/metrs_poem.php?poem=6683). В Академічному тлумачному словнику такого слова немає взагалі, однак в [Словнику лемківської говірки](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/9709/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F) бачимо два значення: 1) сльота, дощова погода; 2) плетун, плетуха. Однак, як мені здається, жодне зі значень не підходить за змістом.

Отож, чи є у слова "папля" ще якесь значення, окрім тих, які я знайшов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=284) наведено 3 значення та походження слова **папля**

> [**папля¹**] «мокра погода»;
>
> очевидно, афективне чи звуконаслідувальне утворення, паралельне до [*ба́бло*] «болото, трясовина» (пор.).
>
> ---
>
> [**папля²**] «халтурник, поганий робітник» Нед, [*па́пляти*] «халтурити, погано працювати» Нед;
>
> білоруська [*па́пля*] «маруда»
>
> очевидно, афективне утворення, паралельне до [*ба́блятися*] «бабратися», чеська piplat «копатися, возитися».
>
> Пор. **[ба́бло](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=106)**.
>
> ---
>
> [**папля³**] (бот.) «крислата тополя, [Populus alba](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_alba) L. ВеБ, ВеНЗн, Mak; осика УЗ БашкГУ 18/8»;
>
> запозичення з німецької мови; нвн. Páppel «тополя» (свн. popel, papel, двн. papilboum) походить від слат. papulus (лат. pōpulus) «тс.».
>
> Kluge—Mitzka 530—531.
>
> Див. ще **[топо́ля](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=600)**.

В представленому контексті слово **паплі** мається на увазі **тополі**.

**Отже:** «Ні дуба, ні клена... Лише землі вклоняються лячно вбогі **тополі**: тремтять на вітрах, і в тиші тремтять, готові лягти під подув розп'ять...»